# Is the "fr-DZ" label ( that we put on the hreflang ) correct for SEO?

Tags: wordpress, seo, wpml, hreflang

Is this code recognizable by google by Google? I mean, is the "DZ" code correct for SEO? I searched about this subject, but any precise answer.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-DZ" href="https://domain.dz/"/>
```

I'm using wpml for translation, and support told me that is not sur that "fr-DZ" are correct for SEO directive.

Any idea about this subject, which can help me? This code is very important for me, to target my audience.

Comment: You probably need to look through the Google's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the guide **[Tell Google about localized versions of your page --> Supported language/region codes](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions#supported-languageregion-codes)**, Google says:

> The value of the hreflang attribute identifies the language (in ISO
> 639-1 format) and optionally a region (in ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 format)
> of an alternate URL. (The language need not be related to the region.)
> For example:
>
> - de: German language content, independent of region
> - en-GB: English language content, for GB users
> - de-ES: German language content, for users in Spain

DZ is the entry for **[Algeria in ISO 3166](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algeria)**. Therefore, your markup is correct for French for Algeria.